# Injecting a new row anywhere in an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working on an invoice website and I would like to be able to add a new row anywhere to my ng-repeat.

Site: http://completeinvoice.com/

**HTML**

```
<tr id="row-{{$index+1}}" class="item-row" ng-repeat="item in invoice.items">
    <td class="col-span2">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InvoiceColOneDetails, new { id = "cel1-row{{$index+1}}", @class = "invoiceColOneDetails", @placeholder = "{{$index+1}}" })</td>
    <td class="col-span6">
        <textarea id="cel2-{{$index+1}}" class="invoiceColTwoDetails" ng-model="item.description" auto-grow></textarea>
    </td>
    <td class="col-span1">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InvoiceColThreeDetails, new { id = "cel3-row{{$index+1}}", @class = "invoiceColThreeDetails text-center", @placeholder = "0", @ng_model = "item.hrsQty" })</td>
    <td class="col-span1">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InvoiceColFourDetails, new { id = "cel4-row{{$index+1}}", @class = "invoiceColFourDetails text-center", @placeholder = "0", @ng_model = "item.ratePrice" })</td>
    <td class="col-span2 relative disabled-field">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InvoiceColFiveDetails, new { id = "cel5-row{{$index+1}}", @class = "invoiceColFiveDetails text-right", @placeholder = "0", @Value = "{{rowTotal(item) | currency}}", @disabled = "disabled" })</td>
    <td class="no-border disabled-field remove-row">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove-item tooltip-right" title="Delete row (Ctrl+Delete)" ng-click="deleteRow($index)">
            <i class="icon-remove-sign"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove-item tooltip-right" title="Insert new row" ng-click="insertRow($index)">
            <i class="icon-add-sign"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Angularjs**

```
$scope.insertRow = function (index) {
    $scope.invoice.items.push({
        description: null,
        hrsQty: null,
        ratePrice: null
    });
};
```

This adds a new row to the bottom of the ng-repeat. Is it even possible to add a new row anywhere in the ng-repeat? I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out.

Comment: Instead of pushing an item onto `$scope.invoice.items`, did you try slicing `items` and then concatenating the pieces together with the one you want to add in the middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$scope.insertRow = function (index) {
var obj={
        description: null,
        hrsQty: null,
        ratePrice: null
    };
    $scope.invoice.items.splice(index,0,obj)
};
```

You can check splice working exampe @ http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Comment: will it regenerate the DOM for all items? or it will just add?

Answer (score 0):

Use `splice` instead of `push`.

For example:

```
> a = [0,1,2]
[0, 1, 2]
> a.splice(1,0,3) // insert 3 at index 1
[]
> a
[0, 3, 1, 2]
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice for details

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
  $scope.insertRow = function (index) {
    var item ={
    description: '',
    hrsQty: 0,
    ratePrice: 0
};
$scope.invoice.items.splice(index,0,item)
       };
```